# how to INNER JOIN(2 tables)

Tags: sql, vb.net

got a little question. I got an error in this code:

```vb
  Private Search As New joiningDataContext

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.Click
        Dim SearchData = Search.SelectData(txtsearch.Text)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = SearchData
```

and this is my stored procedure:

```sql
AS

    SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.middle_name, e.email, d.department_id, d.manager_id
    FROM employee_info AS e
    INNER JOIN departments AS d
    ON employee_info.employee_id=departments.department_id
    WHERE employee_info.employee_id=@employee_id

RETURN
```

it said that, `SelectData` is not a member of `Windowapplication1.joiningDataContext`. 
How can I resolve this one? thanks in advance..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adf5s50k(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6eyh1zec(v=vs.90).aspx

Check those links :)

Comment: Well, SelectData is not a member of joiningDataContext. Are you sure that joiningDataContext has a SelectData method?

Comment: The query isn't right either, but I guess that's not the question.

Comment: @bluejaded nice links.

Comment: Have you added SelectData method to your DataContext??

Comment: so do i need to create a method Selectdata in DataContext? if so what are the possible content of this? just new in this environment, im sorry guys..